# Checking if the value is integer, whether it's int or string at the same time

Tags: php

Since it doesn't really matter if we send `'1'` or `1` to MySQL, or in many other cases in PHP,

I find myself constantly checking like:

```
if(ctype_digit($val) || is_int($val)){
   // Pass
}
```

Basically I want to make sure it is an integer, but it doesn't matter if it's represented as string or int.

#### So I thought:

Maybe there is an equivalent PHP function that does both at the same time that I'm not aware of? please let me know if there is.

Comment: I really hope you're using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check only if the value is integer than:

```
if(intval($val) == $val){
// Pass
}
```

If you want to check value and type in one go, than:

```
if(intval($val) === $val){
// Pass
}
```

Comment: You're right, the first method will work for anything as long as it's positive and smaller than PHP_INT_MAX, (so `$val = PHP_INT_MAX.'1'; if(intval($val) == $val)...` would still fail), thank you very much for the nice first part though.

Comment: You're wrong. My first method works for both positive and negative numbers. Yes, smaller than PHP_INT_MAX. But for PHP_INT_MAX even your own genuine method that you posted in your question - it don't work. Also your method don't work for negative numbers (when they are string type).

Comment: Stackoverflow has been around and answering millions of questions for over 10 years.  Virtually all basic questions are duplicates and should be closed rather than answered.